# C# WebBrowser is it possible to automaticly click an div button?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am testing around with WebBrowser in C# and I found a site which has got an button but the button has no ID it's a div.

```
<div class="pc-image-info-box-button-btn-text pc-cursor"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>GO</div>
```

Is it possible to tell the WebBrowser to click this button?
When the form starts the WebBrowser naviagates to the site than the programm wait's for the WebBrowser to finish loading and once its loaded it should click on the button.

Thats my try right now:

```
            webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(textBox2.Text);

        while(webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript: document.getElementsByClassName('pc-image-info-box-button-btn-text pc-cursor')[0].click();void(0);");
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want to use JQuery or pure JavaScript?

Comment: I would like to keep it going with Javascript as in the code above.
But I don't know if this is possible :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it works, but only if your div has an onclick event handler set.

```
var div = document.createElement('div')
// undefined
div.onclick = function(){ console.log(':)')}
// ƒ (){ console.log(':)')}
div.click()
// :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
    <h2 class="text-center">example</h2>
    <div class="pc-image-info-box-button-btn-text pc-cursor" ><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>GO</div>


</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // attach function on document loaded event
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 

            // Your selector will be different most likely
            var element = document.getElementsByClassName('pc-image-info-box-button-btn-text')[0];

            // add click event listener to selected element
            element.addEventListener("click", clickFunc);

            // declare function which fires on click
            function clickFunc(){ alert('clicked!'); }

            // trigger  element click event
            element.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
        }, false);
    </script>
</html>
```